# USB mouse keeps disconnecting

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse

I have an Onn mouse, and I'm on **Windows 10**, but when I booted up, my mouse suddenly kept disconnecting with the USB disconnect, connect sound. After that, it just flickered and it turned on for a short amount of time, and it only turned on when I clicked.

This is in fact, the *second* time this happened to me just with a different mouse, and it broke, and never worked with any other PC, they just slowly stop working then just, break.

Now I can't get the mouse I was just working with to work, so it just broke like last time. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Try a different USB port. This seems like a unlikely solution. Try a completely different brand of Mouse (e.g. LogiTech or comparable)

Comment: Hello john! My prev mouse was a LogiTech infact. it was the one that also broke too. but ill try your answer.



I recently tried it, But, there are no other ports that could fit a mouse. It's also the one I've been using and the mouses worked fine untill now.

Comment: If all mice have a problem with your port, the port itself might be faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, third party software will also cause driver can't be used successfully. We could boot computer into [Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234) and [Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) to check if mouse works well.

We also could go to device manager, find the mouse driver and update it. Or go to internet to download and install ONN mouse driver.

We also could go to computer manufacturer website do download USB bus driver.
If you suspect it is caused by USB port, we could insert other USB device to check if it works well.